# Add cell value in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

When doing a multi-sheet query, I would like to bring in the value of a cell (A2) from each source sheet to a new column in the results.

The query:

```
=QUERY({CCL!A4:M; HOOD!A4:M; AAL!A4:M; BAC!A4:M;
        LUV!A4:M; T!A4:M; NIO!A4:M; ANY!A4:M; TQQQ!A4:M},
       "SELECT Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7
       WHERE Col13 contains 'OPEN'")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is an exact copy of [Add cell value in query](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/219928879) that has an answer. See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: You have now deleted your question at [Add cell value in query](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/219928879) along with the answer that was given to you. That is less cool than being forthright when cross-posting. Note that deleting questions may discourage contributors from responding to your questions going forward.

Answer (score 0):

#### New Column Formula

For a range `r` in `SheetName`, creates a column with the value `v` from `A2` in that same sheet

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
  IFERROR(
    SEQUENCE(ROWS(r))/0,
    v))
```

#### Added New Column 1 in Formula

New column is selected and existing `Col[n]` references are updated to `Col[n+1]`:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
  { IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(CCL!A4:M))/0,
      CCL!A2), CCL!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(AAL!A4:M))/0,
      AAL!A2), AAL!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(BAC!A4:M))/0,
      BAC!A2), BAC!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(LUV!A4:M))/0,
      LUV!A2), LUV!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(T!A4:M))/0,
      T!A2), T!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(NIO!A4:M))/0,
      NIO!A2), NIO!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ANY!A4:M))/0,
      ANY!A2), ANY!A4:M;
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(TQQQ!A4:M))/0,
      TQQQ!A2), TQQQ!A4:M }),
  "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8
   WHERE Col14 contains 'OPEN'")
```

#### LAMBDA-Based Alternative

This approach reduces duplication.

The [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) function enables storing intermediary calculations and values in arbitrarily named variables, and the [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function generalizes a formula using variables as placeholders for values.  Combined, this allows the same [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) formula to be reapplied to completely new values.

```
=LET(arr, LAMBDA(r, ARRAYFORMULA(
   { IFERROR(
       SEQUENCE(ROWS(r))/0,
       OFFSET(INDEX(r,1,1),-2,0)), r })),
  QUERY(
    { arr(CCL!A4:M); arr(AAL!A4:M);
      arr(BAC!A4:M); arr(LUV!A4:M);
      arr(T!A4:M);   arr(NIO!A4:M);
      arr(ANY!A4:M); arr(TQQQ!A4:M) },
    "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8
     WHERE Col14 contains 'OPEN'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample spreadsheet you shared earlier suggests that the sheets you want to include are listed in `E5:E` and should be filtered based on the checkboxes in `D5:D`.

Use `filter()`, `reduce()` and `indirect()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  stackSheets_, lambda(sn,ra,h,reduce(h,sn,lambda(rs,s,let(r,indirect(s&"!"&ra),l,max(index(row(r)*iferror(r<>""))),d,filter(r,row(r)<=l),r_,lambda(v,byrow(d,lambda(_,v))),if(counta(iferror(d)),vstack(rs,hstack(r_(indirect(s&"!A2")),d)),rs))))), 
 
  sheetNames, filter(E5:E, D5:D), 
  headers, { "SHEET NAME", NIO!A3:Q3 }, 
  data, stackSheets_(sheetNames, "A4:Q", headers), 
 
  query(data, "select Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9 where Col18 contains 'OPEN' label Col2 'STRATEGY' ", 1) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amCz9C9XgCv4pc1MjbP6zJHPPTLb4CnoJK3V_oYdsHw/edit#gid=1661140067).